# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Mybatis :Bulk update query using foreach

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

Following is a bulk update query i have written using `foreach` and `update` statement. In this apart from `update_time` any other parameter can be null.
This query is supposed to take a list of objects as parameter and return void.

```
<update id="bulkUpdate" parameterType="java.util.List">
<foreach collection="list" item="item"  index="index"  separator=";" >
    UPDATE 
     <include refid="tableName" /> 
    <set>
             update_time=#{item.updateTime}
            <if test="item.testFlg != null">, test_flg=#{item.testFlg}</if>
            <if test="item.DueDate != null">, due_date=#{item.DueDate}</if>
            <if test="item.versionId != null">, version_id=#{item.versionId}</if>
     </set>
     WHERE
    <include refid="tableName" />.order_id=#{item.orderId} 
</foreach>
</update>
```

After Debugging i found that the query is getting all the required not null values correctly. However I am getting this error that is driving me crazy.

```
The error occurred while setting parameters\r\n### SQL: UPDATE        glb_order_tbl        SET update_time=?                                                                                                                                                                                                   , complete_due_date=?                          , version_id=?       WHERE      glb_order_tbl .order_id=? ;             UPDATE        glb_order_tbl        SET update_time=?                                                                                                                                                                                                   , complete_due_date=?                          , version_id=?       WHERE      glb_order_tbl .order_id=? \r\n### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE \n      glb_order_tbl  \n     SET update_time='2015-02-24 13:01:48.608'\n   ' at line 24\n; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE \n      glb_order_tbl  \n     SET update_time='2015-02-24 13:01:48.608'\n   ' at line 24"
```

It seems some sort of syntactical error that i can't find out.
I am using `Java+spring+MyBatis+MySql`

**Updated Query and error.Please note that parameters being set(inside set block) might have changed**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you set the `open`, `close` and `separator` incorrectly in your `foreach` closure.

In your sql, it appends `(` at the beginning of the whole sql, and `)` at the end, and separate each `update` sql with `,`. The generated sql surely has the syntactical error.

Change it as follows, and it should work.

```
<foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=";">
```

Comment: Thank you @Landys. I was able to figure that out after properly understanding foreach statement and modified my statement as per your answer .However its still giving same error although on different line .
And i was able to do multiple  updates using the "wrong" query via workbench.
I would like to point out that i am using simple mybatis executor .Do i need to use batch executor or something ..??

Comment: do you enable the multiple update in the jdbc url?  If not ,you should append the parameter `allowMultiQueries=true` into the url of jdbc .